# C# data annotations for model's prop not formatted? - type double

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, data-annotations

I have a class with a data annotation `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]` that dose not format at all. I have included the `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;` in my class as well.

Below is my class:

```
    public class StepTwo : IEnumerable
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Party { get; set; }
        public string Currency { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public double? Amount { get; set; }

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```

Now when I use this class in my program, the numbers are not formatted? I know I can do this in a Razor page but the whole point of using data annotations is so you don't have to do this everywhere.

I have tried `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true), DataFormatString = "{0:n2}"]` but it has not changed anything.

I'm not sure why this isn't formatted? What am I missing?

Thanks for your help, appreciate some advise.

I've included the Razor page relevant below:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    @foreach (var cus in Model.SSTwo)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@cus.Id</td>
            <td>@cus.Currency</td>
            <td>@cus.Party</td>
            <td>@cus.Amount</td>

        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Please include your razor/view code

Comment: @jcruz, I've added it in

Answer (score 0):

You have set the ApplyFormatInEditMode = true so the formating will work only in the edit mode, just remove it to see the formating work in view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
@foreach (var cus in Model.SSTwo)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@cus.Id</td>
        <td>@cus.Currency</td>
        <td>@cus.Party</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem=>cus.Amount)</td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```